# How can I convert a java.util.Date object to the restricted form of the canonical representation of dateTime

Tags: java, xml, datetime

I need to convert a java.util.Date variable to a representation similar to the one below.

```
 1995-12-31T23:59:59.999Z
```

The format for this date field is of the form 1995-12-31T23:59:59Z, and  is a more restricted form of the canonical representation of dateTime http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime.

The trailing "Z" designates UTC time and is mandatory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
System.out.println(df.format(new Date()));
```

Output:

```
2010-02-14T06:38:48.920Z
```

Here you're manually setting the time zone on the date formatter to UTC.

Comment: I was using this particularly for Solr. For this, Solr has already provided a DateField class inside the core library. org.apache.solr.schema.DateField. This can also be used for that purpose.